# Set position of draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm doing a little application using jQuery and JQuery ui.

I've defined a dragable div, and it works perfectly, but I want to set the position of the div when a click a button...

I read here in stackOverflow to do this:

```
element.position().top = topUserDefined;
element.position().left = leftUserDefined;
```

I did an alert of element.position().top before and after this assignment and the new value it's not assigned, it keeps the original one...

Any Idea???
Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) gets the position. It doesn't set the position. It actually uses [`element.offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft) and `element.offsetTop` (compared to `element.offsetParent` position) those are read only.

Change inline CSS value to move your element:

```
element.css({'top': 10, 'left' : 20})
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! Working now... I don't know why I was trying to do something more difficult...

Comment: It always happens! :) Y U No select this answer as correct? :D